# Owl-items initial with 0px

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm having an issue with owl-carousel when I try and incorporate it with a website. Essentially the owl-wrapper and all owl-item instances have a width set to 0 inline, and I can't work out why.

If I manually resize the windows, it works properly. You can see [here](http://colormyepiphany.com/vibrant-works/) (What Peopel Say area) you can search for owl-slider in the DOM and see this output which is obviously wrong:

[image]

I've tried various things but can't seem to fix the site. Can anyone provide me with a solution or some suggestions on things to continue trying?

Comment: The initialisation script `$("#testimonials-0 .testimonials-list").owlCarousel(` is above the owl-carousal js file. Try to add it after `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://colormyepiphany.com/wp-content/themes/tm-heli/assets/libs/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js?ver=2.0'></script>`and check once.

Comment: @CharantejGolla I have tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: it is working.Copy your website source code and add it in html and change the script as i said. then see the output it'll work. I tried it and commented here.

Comment: @CharantejGolla Please check my page again, now owl-carousel below script but it still doesn't work.

Comment: No it was stilll before `http://colormyepiphany.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/owl-carousel2-dist/owl.carousel.min.js?ver=4.11.2.1` script. `ctrl + u` takes you to view source. Find `owlCarousel` it was in line number `516` and the script was in `755`.

Comment: @CharantejGolla Thank you so much. I figured out, the issue was resolved.